# Select box not showing the selected option first

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-forms

I am using angular 6 and i am unable to display the selected option as default in select box,

**HTML** consists,

```
<select class="form-control selectBox" name="username" #username="ngModel" required ngModel>
<option disabled selected>Select User Name</option>
<option *ngFor="let user of userList" [value]="user.uid">{{user.name }}</option>
</select>
```

**Ts:**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';
  userList: any = [
    {
      "name" : "Test User"
    },
    {
      "name" : "Hello World"
    },
    {
      "name" : "User Three"
    }
  ]
}
```

It is showing empty value as default inside the select box.

How can i show the selected option as default inside the select box which from the line?

```
<option disabled selected>Select User Name</option>
```

**Stackblitz:**https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wfjmlm

Comment: Do you need `ngModel`? It works without it. See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xepxxi).

Comment: @ConnorsFan, I do need ngModel ..```value=" "``` worked for me....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to set a value in select box like this:

```
<option disabled selected value="">Select User Name</option>
```

Will make it work.

Answer (score 2):

add `[value]=""`

```
<option disabled [value]="" selected>Select User Name</option>
```

and if you want to hide disable option then add `hidden` attribute

```
<option hidden disabled [value]="" selected>Select User Name</option>
```

Answer (score 2):

the solution can be found in as follows
following was html

```
<select class="form-control selectBox" name="username" [(ngModel)]="selected" required>
 <option disabled selected>Select User Name</option>
 <option *ngFor="let user of userList" >{{user.name }}</option>
</select>
<hr>   {{selected}}
```

following was the controller

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  name = 'Angular';
  userList: any = [
    {
      "name": "Test User"
    },
    {
      "name": "Hello World"
    },
    {
      "name": "User Three"
    }
  ];
  selected = 'Select User Name';
}
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gozukc?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Answer (score 1):

### ReactiveForms

I pretty much suggest using ReactiveForms. In this way you will have a cleaner code as well as more powerful options.

first import ReactiveForms to your `app.module`:

```
import {FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
...
   imports: [
      ...
      ReactiveFormsModule
      ...
   ]
```

Then in your controller:

```
myForm: FormGroup;
constructor(private fb: FormBuilder){
    this.myForm = this.fb.group({
          username: null
      })
}
```

And in your template:

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm">
   <select formControlName="username" placeholder="Select Username">
        <option disabled selected>Select User Name</option>
        <option *ngFor="let user of userList" [value]="user.uid">{{user.name }}</option>
  </select>
```

Answer (score -2):

Use angular material instead of select and option.
Like this for example:

```
   <mat-form-field>
      <mat-select placeholder="Select User Name">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let user of userList" [value]="user.uid">
          {{food.viewValue}}
        </mat-option>
      </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
```

More details here: https://material.angular.io/components/select/overview

Comment: They can fix what they have.  There's no need to introduce even more libraries.

Comment: It's a solution like another don't need to downvote ^^
Depending what you want and the style as well

Comment: I consider telling someone to use a library to solve a simple problem as a bad answer.  It's like buying a new car because your headlights in your current car need replacing - it's overkill.

Comment: As I said, it also provides implemented style. It was also because he used angular so in my opinion it could be good to implement angular material or primeNG  for example but whatever ahah

Comment: Don't take it personally.  I consider it bad advice so I have to downvote it.  Keep answering questions and don't take things to heart - we all get downvoted sometimes :)